# Add border around chat ticker

Tags: html, css, chat, border

Just want to add a border around this chat ticker. This is a generated chat script from the website. There are no options via website to add a border. Tried a couple of different html/css examples but no luck. Just want to change border color and line thickness.

[Screenshot of mobile chat ticker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVe3n.jpg)

```
<script id="cid0020000253835420517" data-cfasync="false" 
async src="//st.chatango.com/js/gz/emb.js" style="width: 803px;height: 300px;">.{"handle":"webupdatetools","arch":"js","styles":
{"a":"E26A6A","b":100,"c":"000000","d":"000000","k":"E26A6A",
"l":"E26A6A","m":"E26A6A","p":"10","q":"E26A6A",
"r":100,"pos":"br","cv":1,"cvfnt":"trebuchet ms, sans-serif","cvfntsz":"15px","cvfntw":"bolder","cvbg"
:"E26A6A","cvfg":"2c3e50","cvw":803,"cvh":36,"ticker":1,"fwtickm":1}}</script>
```

Comment: You'll have to provide the link of the page where this chat box is used, other we can't find the tight CSS Selector.

Comment: https://www.chatango.com/ anything between the <script></script> is the entire code of the chat. There is no CSS.

Comment: There is no chat box on this site.